# Error in conversion from binary value to double in c#

Tags: c#, c++, binaryreader

I'm trying to read a *binary file* made from a **c++** program.
This file has some `double` numbers and, when I tried to read them, I get a *wrong* `double` value.

This is the HEX value read from the file:

```
00-67-CC-02-B3-F7-40-CA
```

**Expected** value:

```
0.2051076530529798
```

**Actual** value:

```
-4.9596277989715114E+49
```

Binary file type: `double` **8** byte (**c++**)

Conversion output in **c#**: `double` (`binaryreader.ReadDouble()`)

This is the code:

```
reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open), Encoding.Default);

double value = reader.ReadDouble();
```

I already checked, i'm using this command in the right position. Why do I have this *different value*?

Comment: Did you check [endianness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: This sounds like an endian issue

Comment: No, it is not an endian issue. As Dmitry said, I was reading a byte shifted 1 position to the left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's have a look at the `expected` repesented as `byte`s:

```
double expected = 0.2051076530529798;

string result = string.Join("-", BitConverter
  .GetBytes(expected)
  .Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
66-CC-02-B3-F7-40-CA-3F
```

Let's **compare** it with your input:

```
00-67-CC-02-B3-F7-40-CA    // Your input 
   66-CC-02-B3-F7-40-CA-3F // Should be for 0.2051076530529798
```

It seems that you should *skip* `1` *byte* (you read the stream at the *wrong position*).

```
// I've assumed that the next byte is `3F`
// Your input without starting `00` but with final `3F`
string data = "67-CC-02-B3-F7-40-CA-3F";

double value = BitConverter.ToDouble(data
    .Split('-')
    .Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, 16))
    .ToArray(), 
  0);

Console.Write(value);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 0.20510765305298
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

For this case I think you have to look at the issue of marshalling .

> C# marshalling (C# call C++ DLL)
>
> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1201571/Csharp-marshalling-Csharp-call-Cplusplus-DLL
>
> https://mark-borg.github.io/blog/2017/interop/

Comment: Please include relevant info in the response in case the links become inaccessible in the future.